# How to enforce alpha channel when using PIL.ImageGrab and cv2.imread?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I use `PIL.ImageGrab` to take a screenshot:

```py
screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(869,657,955,714))
screen.save("PictureName.png")
```

Later, I use `cv2.imread` to open that image, and want to get the alpha channel:

```py
template = cv2.imread('PictureName.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
hh, ww = template.shape[:2]
alpha = template[:,:,3]
alpha = cv2.merge([alpha,alpha,alpha])
cv2.imshow('alpha',alpha)
```

That doesn't work, and I get the following error:

```
alpha = template[:,:,3] -> index 3 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 3
```

How can I fix this in order to make this code work?

Comment: Your original image simply has no alpha channel, cf. `template.shape` is `(57, 85, 3)`, such that there's no index 3 for axis 2. By the way, the second image also has no alpha channel. For this one, the given code also fails!?

Comment: @HansHirse so ImageGrab from PIL does not grab with alpha ?

Comment: Why `ImageGrab`? Your code is all about OpenCV, cf. `cv2.imread`!?

Comment: @HansHirse because the first image in my exemple is grabed and saved with imagegrab ...

Comment: Ok. Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66385407/edit) your question, and describe in detail, what your actual problem is? Please provide the whole, necessary code to reproduce your actual error, and please provide the ORIGINAL image.

Comment: @HansHirse just did ;) sorry. The original Image is generated with `ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(869,657,955,714))` and the second whone is generated with windows screenshot tool... 
How would I use ImageGrab to get a picture with alpha then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229247/discussion-between-dorian-and-hanshirse).

Comment: @HansHirse By The way, does a way exist to add alpha channel to template ? 
Or should I take screenshot again ? If yes What should I do to get AlphaChannel in my Image using `ImageGrab` or other stuff ? Thank you

Comment: `screen.convert('RGBA').save("PictureName.png")`

Comment: @HansHirse thank you, no way to directly convert `Template` after opening ? `template = cv2.imread('PictureName.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`

Comment: `template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)`, but just in case `template.shape` is `(x, y, 3)`, otherwise this will fail.

Comment: @HansHirse thank you so much, feel free to put it as answer. Think it should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is, that by default `PIL.ImageGrab` uses `Image` objects with mode `RGB`. So, the saved image has no alpha channel. Even when using `cv2.imread(..., cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`, the resulting NumPy array will have shape `(height, width, 3)`, such that accessing `template[..., 3]` will lead to the given error.

So, there seem to be two options to improve your code in terms of enforcing the alpha channel.

1. After grabbing the screenshot, convert the `Image` object to mode `RGBA`, and then save.
2. When opening the image, check `template.shape[2] == 3`, and if necessary, use `cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)`.

Here's some code snippet:

```py
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab

# Force alpha channel in screenshot saving
screen = ImageGrab.grab((0, 0, 200, 200))
screen.save('image_rgb.png')
screen.convert('RGBA').save('image_rgba.png')


# If necessary, add alpha channel after reading the image
def force_alpha_read(filename):
    print('DEBUG:', filename)
    image = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    if image.shape[2] == 3:
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
        print('DEBUG: Added alpha channel')
    return image


template = force_alpha_read('image_rgb.png')
print(template.shape)

template = force_alpha_read('image_rgba.png')
print(template.shape)
```

That's the output:

```
DEBUG: image_rgb.png
DEBUG: Added alpha channel
(200, 200, 4)
DEBUG: image_rgba.png
(200, 200, 4)
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```